# How can I install this GridMarkeys_Envoy.tar.gz package

Tags: software-installation, tar

I've download a .tar.gz package ("GridMarkets_Envoy.tar.gz").

I've used the following command to extract the archive:

```
tar -xzf archive-name.tar.gz
```

Then, I navigated to extraction directory.
In the directory, I can't find a configure file.
So I can't use the familiar commands to install.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This is a screenshot of the extracted directory.

[[image: Extracted archive files][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwHh1.png)

I've tried to execute the ./gridmarkets file in Terminal but I get the following error.

[image: Terminal result]

Comment: Look for an installation manual or requirements. tar is an archive, there is no generic method to install what is located in any archive.

Comment: And what is the Ubuntu version? Is there `libgconf-2.so.4`?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
I've searched for a libgconf, but there isn't any in the package.

Comment: Can you find `libgconf-2.so.4` in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` or `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: I added the answer. Try to install `libgconf-2-4`. Maybe you'll need `i386` if the program is 32-bit.

Comment: I've searched for libgconf in both directories but there is no libgconf file.

Comment: So install it. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a binary package. You don't need to install it. It requires `libgconf-2.so.4` that is provided by `libgconf-2-4` package.

Install it by

```
sudo apt install libgconf-2-4
```

Run the program by

```
./gridmarkets
```

form the directory where it is located.